# DirectShowNet and annoying screen

Tags: c#, winforms, camera, directshow

I'm using DirectShowNet.dll to grab a photo
of my web camera.

Anytime my camera initializes it first shows me this 
screen. Where can I turn it off?

http://www.goat-it.com/!tino/screen.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is pulling up the prop pages for your camera.  I have only been able to get this property page to show if I explicitly write code to do it.  How are you getting the image?  Graph -> CaptureGraphBuilder2 + SampleGrabber -> SampleGrabberCB?

Comment: Yes, this is just the way I do it...
I'm new to DirectShow, so I've downloaded some sample code
for grabbing images from camera. I don't have a very good
understanding how it works.

How do you explicitly write code to show this screen?

Comment: Here, I do it in my open source project here: http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40116#25940

Look at the ShowCapturePropertyPages(...) method and follow to PropertyPageHelper.cs

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Win32 FindWindow command to find it and then send a WM_COMMAND to press the OK button?

Edit:  Well if you want to do it the more "proper" way (Though my experience is from the C++ end, but I assume its much the same) you may want to locate the video capture filter.  Once you've located that you can query interface it to see if you can access its IPropertyPage (IIRC) interface.  If you can then you should just be able to call Deactivate.

Alas I don't have access to a webcam at the moment so I can't check on how exactly to do this ...

Are you using the ICaptureGraphBuilder?  If so it may well be worth learning how to enumerate all the devices and attach them together yourself.  It will give you a MUCH better understanding of whats going on :)

Comment: That sounds to me more like a hack...
I will surely try it, but, I'm interested in 
what is triggering that window to show?
Is it DirectShow's window  or internal Windows property window?

It pops out no matter what camera I connect to it, so it's
not related to a specific webcam.